# How can I remove an undesired indentation?

Tags: beamer, indentation

I've got the following frame:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{TP-Basis}
Ausgangspunkt: 
\begin{align*}
s(x) = \begin{cases} a+bx & x \leq k \\ c+dx & x > k \end{cases}
\end{align*}
\only<2>{
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=.70\textwidth]{PiecewiseLinear_2}
\end{figure}}
\only<3->{Um eine stetige Funktion zu erhalten, wird eine zusätzliche Bedingung benötigt: 
\begin{align*}
& &  a + bk &= c + dk\\
\Leftrightarrow & & c &= a+bk-dk \\
\Leftrightarrow & & c &= a+bk-dk +  \underbrace{bx-bx}_\text{=0}
\end{align*}
}
\end{frame}
```

Everything's fine, however the word "Um" gets indented. I'd like that sentence to be aligned with "Ausgangspunkt".

How would I go about doing that? I've tried `\noindent`without success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an "unprotected" end of line that counts as a space:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{TP-Basis}
Ausgangspunkt:
\begin{align*}
s(x) = \begin{cases} a+bx & x \leq k \\ c+dx & x > k \end{cases}
\end{align*}
\only<2>{%
  \includegraphics[width=.70\textwidth]{PiecewiseLinear_2}%
}% <---- THIS IS IMPORTANT
\only<3->{Um eine stetige Funktion zu erhalten, wird eine zusätzliche Bedingung benötigt:
\begin{align*}
& &  a + bk &= c + dk\\
\Leftrightarrow & & c &= a+bk-dk \\
\Leftrightarrow & & c &= a+bk-dk +  \underbrace{bx-bx}_\text{=0}
\end{align*}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I've added other `%` where also needed.

Don't use the `figure` environment: there's no need for it.

If you want to center the image, just tell LaTeX to do it:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{TP-Basis}
Ausgangspunkt:
\begin{align*}
s(x) = \begin{cases} a+bx & x \leq k \\ c+dx & x > k \end{cases}
\end{align*}

\only<2>{
  \begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=.70\textwidth]{PiecewiseLinear_2}
  \end{center}
}

\only<3->{Um eine stetige Funktion zu erhalten, wird eine zusätzliche Bedingung benötigt:
\begin{align*}
& &  a + bk &= c + dk\\
\Leftrightarrow & & c &= a+bk-dk \\
\Leftrightarrow & & c &= a+bk-dk +  \underbrace{bx-bx}_\text{=0}
\end{align*}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

With this second way, unprotected end-of-lines don't sneak in as spaces in the output.

Comment: `beamer` redefines the figure environment. So it is no floating objects. However you can use it for captions ;-)

Comment: If I leave out the `figure` the image is no longer centred. Using `\center`doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: @user2249626 I've added a different way for centering

Comment: @user2249626 It's totally equal to use `center` or `figure`.